# NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined37

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am using virtual box with Ubuntu and when trying to run this below command, it appears me this error any idea what is going on? You can see it more clearly down the code!!

**Code:**

```
(flaskenv) argiris@argiris-VirtualBox:~/myprojects/FlaskIntro$ python3 app.py
```

**Error:**

```
/home/argiris/myprojects/FlaskIntro/flaskenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Todo(db.Model):
  File "app.py", line 11, in Todo
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
(flaskenv) argiris@argiris-VirtualBox:~/myprojects/FlaskIntro$ vim app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    date_completed = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=date(2000,1,1))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id
    
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to  import datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: it appears me other error                                                                      line 13, in Todo
date_completed = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=date(2000,1,1))
NameError: name 'date' is not defined